# How to apply custom CSS in omniscript

Tags: css, omniscript

I am trying to apply custom CSS to a particular node in the Omniscript for the particular element,
i am getting error and custom  CSS is not being applied.

CSS class :-

```
slds-form-element__label slds-show--inline{
```

color: red;
}

---

.omnistudio-input_input_slds
{
color: red;
}

both are throwing error on compilation error  and not getting applied

Trying to achieve as below :-
element.style {
font-size: 28px;
color: indianred;
}

I am new to omnistudio, any help will be appreciated.